# Is it possible to have a Storyboard within a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have a project that started out without a Storyboard. I now realise that it is very difficult to implement Table View Controller because of the numerous xibs that I will need. After doing a search, I was recommended to create a Storyboard to "encapsulate" the Table View Controller. However, can I do that for within a Tab in a Tab Bar Controller?

Can't quite draw here, but the UI would look like the following:

1. On screen, a Tab Bar Controller exists with 4 different Tabs, that was created with xibs
2. In each of these Tabs, I'd like to have a Table View Controller that is using Storyboard

Any idea? Thanks! :) Any sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me like you are could use more information about the basics of Storyboards, I recommend you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Whether they come from storyboards or .xib files, the result is objects that are subclasses of `UIViewController`.  Mixing how you create them, storyboard, .xib, or even directly in code, works fine.

You can get a reference to a storyboard object by name and then instantiate a view controller, either as the initial one or by naming it.  You thenpush or present it as you need to.

Comment: Hello Phillip, thanks for the quick response. Any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "have a storyboard within a tab bar controller", but rather the other way around, a tab bar controller scene (and four table view controller scenes) within a storyboard. To do that, one would:

1. Drag a "tab bar controller" onto your storyboard.
2. Drag four "table view controllers" onto your storyboard, too.
3. One-by-one, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the tab bar controller's scene to the table view controller scenes:

   [image: control drag]

   When you let go, you will be presented with a popover list of segue types, which you can then choose "Relationship Segue - View Controllers". That will add a tab associated with that table view controller scene to your tab bar controller scene.

   [image: relationship - view controller]
4. You can then get rid of the blank scenes that were included automatically when you first added the tab bar controller to your scene.

   If you haven't already, you'll probably want to specify the tab bar controller as the "is initial view controller" option on the attributes inspector for the tab bar controller scene.

Having done all of that you can now proceed to set the base classes for your four table view controller scenes and configure them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented tab bar controller in a project with xib. their seems no issue in implementing tab bar controller with xib or storyboard. as philip said both are the one and the same thing they are just called differently. but tab bar controller is define in the app delegate so their seems no need to change the code. just create the objects for the `UIViewCOntroller` in `app delegate` and pass it to `UITabbar` item so it will directly call the all tableview controller you want to call. if need any details in this you can ask its not difficult task